# const CFoo &bar() const

Tags: c++

I have a property of a class, for example, `const CFoo &bar() const`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method `bar` returns a reference to a const `CFoo` (that's the `const CFoo &` part before `bar`), and calling this method does not modify any variables that are not marked as `mutable` (that's the `const` after the parentheses).

See also the C++ FAQ Lite entries [*What does "`Fred const& X`" mean?*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.6) and [*What is a "`const` member function"?*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10).

Answer (score 9):

```
const CFoo& bar() const
----------      --------
      ^               ^
Returns a connst      None of the member variables of the class to which bar
reference of CFoo.    method belongs to can be modified.
                      unless member variable is prefexex with keyword mutable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a const function (doesn't modify any non-mutable members of the object) member function that returns a reference to a const CFoo.