# Parameter to a function in C++

Tags: c++, parameters, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [const CFoo &bar() const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742084/const-cfoo-bar-const)

Which is the meaning of this line?

```
virtual void Encode (KDataStream & stream) const;
```

What´s the meaning of const at the end in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the meaning of this line?

```
virtual void Encode (KDataStream & stream) const;
```

It's a statement that declares a function.

`virtual` means it's a member function that can be overridden by a function of the same name and compatible parameter and return types declared in a class derived from this one. The correct version will be chosen (at run-time, if necessary) according to the type of the object it's invoked on.

`void` means it doesn't return anything.

`Encode` is the name of the function.

`(` marks the start of the parameter list.

`KDataStream` is the type of the first parameter.

`&` means the parameter is passed by reference.

`stream` is the name given to the parameter; it serves as documentation, but can be left out of the declaration without changing the meaning.

`)` marks the end of the parameter list.

`const` means that it's a member function that can't modify non-static, non-mutable data members of the object it's invoked on. It also allows it to be invoked on objects that are declared `const`.

`;` marks the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

It means -- [pass by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

Comment: The question is about the meaning of trailing const.

Comment: This person [dani] changed the question. As you can see , the second answer say "It's a reference variable".

Answer (score 1):

The 'const' at the end of the method says that the method implementation will not change the values of any member variables. So, by seeing this in the class interface itself (without having to know the implementation), the clients of the object can know about this behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on pointers, if you want to code in c++ you will need to know how these work:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

& means you are passing in the memory address of stream rather the value of stream

Comment: Seriously, did you even read the question? This is far off, completely misleading and peppered with a link to a horrible tutorial.

Comment: The question was changed

Comment: Even without the change in the question this is still horribly wrong.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy: Nothing in the question has anything to do with pointers. The use of `&` in a declaration (as in the question) to declare a reference is completely different to its use in an expression (as in your link) to take the address of an object.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realise there was a difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference